# C++ singleton object with derived objects function calls

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, singleton

It might be already answered but it has bothered me a lot by giving me headaches so that's why I'm asking for a solution or an explanation.

The thing is that I'm developing a system in which I want to have only one properties(in terms of application) struct or sth accessible from everywhere in my code.
To give you the bigger plan I want to hold all my properties in an class object lets say Properties. So I decided to go with the Singleton on this one. 
The point is that I want derived objects with their values and getter-setter methods coming from the base class Properties. 
For example I want to have let's say two different objects from two different classes Component1Properties and Component2Properties. Now I want my Properties singleton to create a Components1Properties object and one Component2Properties object so that every-time I'm getting the same instance I'll have the same derived objects.
Now next let's add a static string "property" to each of the derived object and also declare a getter and setter method for this string.

The problem I'm facing is that I want from everywhere in my code to call the derived objects functions and get and set the values inside these objects
Example: 
In my .h file:

```
class Properties
{
public:

static Properties& getInstance() 
{
 if instance==NULL} instance = new Properties();
return *instance;
}

private:

Properties();
static Properties* instance;
};

class Compoment1Properties : public Properties
{
public:
String property1;
void setProperty1(String value){
     property1 = value;
}
String getValue(){
     return property1
}
Component1Properties();
~Component1Properties(){};
};
```

Then in my .cpp file I have

```
Properties::Properties()
{
 Component1Properties component1Properties;
}
```

I want from everywhere in the code to be able to get or set the values of the Component1Properties with something like:

String value = Properties::getInstance().component1Properties.getValue();
Properties::getInstance().component1Properties.setValue(value);

My questions here are
1. Is this feasible somehow ? 
2. Is the architecture correct based on my needs ?
3. I'm I doing anything wrong ?

Thanks for your understanding and sorry if this is something to obvious but actually I'm trying to get familiarised with OOP principles in C++ but things are pretty messed up for me and I'm only getting headaches instead of results.

Comment: Provide an interface or use `dynamic_cast<ComponentProperties&>(Properties::getInstance())`. Anyway that kind of design smells a bit.

Comment: Can you be more clear about second code snippet? What you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, What I want is to create Component{1,2}Properties objects inside my Properties constructor. However, as Petr pointed out in his reply this is not feasible, thus I need to change my design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have it working directly the way you want, simply because if you want to be able to have *two* objects `Component1Properties` and `Component2Properties`, both having `Properties` as a base class, then you will have *at least two* copies of `Properties` class: one in each component properties. This is just how inheritance works, but this clearly breaks your singleton approach.

What you *can* do is to have `Component1Properties` hold a *reference* (or, well, pointer) to a `Properties` object, and the same for `Component2Properties`. In this case it will be possible to share `Properties` object between component properties objects.

You can then have `Properties` object produce objects for particular components, most probably via some factory pattern, though I would suggest a separate class for this, like `PropertiesFactory`. It might as well be a singleton or even be contained in in `Properties` class, though even better might be main `PropertiesManager` class that is a factory producing global `Properties` as well as properties for each object.

---

Another approach that might be feasible if each component properties is just a subset of global properties. In such a case, you can have separate `Component{1,2}Properties` classes and `Properties` class that inherits all `ComponentXProperties`:

```
class Properties : public Component1Properties, Component2Properties {
};
```

In this case, you can just cast the global Properties object to any class you need. You may also try tricks with virtual inheritance here if your components have some properties in common, but overall this seems to be too complex and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Registry Based Singletons

1. Use map of Pointers to base class in BASE class for storing objects and class name.
2. Use protected methods register and unregister in BASE class which accept BASE* and string name for derived class. register and unregister methods insert and remove objects from map, respect. CAREFUL with removal, as removing objects from does not mean invoking destructor!!
3. Add static lookup method to base class so as to check if object is in map.
   3.In DERIVED class, constructors are private. for getInstance you need to do lookup first and if it returns no object, instantiate using private constructor and Register That object with Current derived class name.